# Making buffer zone based on size of attribute using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, vector

Buffer zone isn't really the correct word, sorry, but I am not sure how to explain it.

I want to make a circle around each attribute based of the size of the value, similar to a bubble map. However, I also need to select the overlaps to see which area has the largest overlap (does this make sense?)

I am using Vector data (I think) in the form of xlsx datafile (need to geo-code this first) and I do have access to a large amount of GIS programs (school computer)

How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using ArcGIS, the [Buffer (Analysis)](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/buffer.htm) tool contains a buffer_distance_or_field value, wherein you can input your distance attribute field to buffer.

The second part of your question is best asked as another question, but you would do an [Intersect (Analysis)](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/intersect.htm) operation.